# Securing expo - react native app from decompiling?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i'm so new to this , is there anyway i can secure the app from decompiling or reverse engineering? , or at least make it hard to get to the main code?

i'm using expo , idk if it's an easy thing to decompile and get to the app code , i'm testing api calls and learning on some of app ideas i have , compile it to apk and sharing it for testing/fun , so if it's not an easy thing to do i can go on and learn about security later, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting `enableProguardInReleaseBuilds` to `true` in `android>app> build.gradle` file will make it hard...

It'll also shrink your app size...